# Apache: How to redirect request to port 3001 if my port 3000 is unavailable

Tags: apache

I have go lang server running on port 3000 and on port 3001.

My go lang servers have to run behind Apache.

My problem statement: I want my request to always go on port 3000 but in case my go server on port 3000 is down then my request should route to go server on port 3001.

Can someone please help me with the apache conf of this problem statement.
Thank you in advance.

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

ProxyErrorOverride Off

<Proxy>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/status$
RewriteRule ^/status$ http://localhost:3001/ [P,L]
```

Got this conf file but it is not routing req to port 3001 if my port 3000 is down

Comment: Look into [mod-balancer](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html), will allow you to do exactly this.

Comment: Thank you.
I tried doing by that and it met my requirement.